# How to express argument of type QVariantList in qdbus command line tool

Tags: qt4

Hello I'm trying to call an D-Bus interface method using qdbus command line tool, but I can't express one of the parameters of type QVariantList. How to express it so the call would pass and a result wouldn't be a message "Could not convert 'x' to type 'QVariantList'".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My coworker found the answer. It is expressed as "(" "element" ")" so an empty QVariantList is "(" ")".